# Separating a Factorial Expression into a Telescoping Sequence

Tags: calculus

In my Calculus 2 course, we were asked to make the expression: 
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{(n + k)!} 
$$
into a telescoping sequence. In the past we have done things like: 
$$
\frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
What I am trying to figure out is how to get the uppermost expression to look like the one just above. It is an infinite sum of an with n being the variable and k being some fixed natural number. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

$\frac {1}{n!} = \frac {n+1}{(n+1)!} = \frac {n}{(n+1)!} + \frac {1}{(n+1)!}\\
\frac {1}{(n+1)!} = \frac {1}{n!} - \frac {n}{(n+1)!}\\
\frac {1}{(n+1)!} = \frac {1}{n!} - \frac {(n+1)}{(n-1)!}\\
$

Comment: How would k be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac1{(n+k)!} &= \sum_{j=n+k}^\infty\left( \frac1{j!}-\frac1{(j+1)!}\right)
\\&=\sum_{j=n+k}^\infty\frac{j}{(j+1)!}.
\end{align}